# Google spreadsheet Query Error - column doesn't exist

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Another problem with Google Spreadsheet API. I'm trying to use `QUERY()` function in order to get all customers from our database who are from Warsaw. Google API seems however to have a big problem with parsing my query. I've checked it few times and everything is OK. Tried semicolons, different apostrophes and column names—it still won't work. I type this code in the sheet cell:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("0ArsOaWajjzv9dEdGTUZCWFc1NnFva05uWkxETVF6Q0E"; "Kuchnia polska!A3:G40"); "select B where E contains 'Warszawa'")
```

And get error like this:

```
Invalid query: Column [E] does not exist in table.
```

And I'm 110% sure that the column exists and the spreadsheet key is OK. ;)

Answer (score 39):

If you are using the `Query` function with a direct reference to a rectangle of cells, then you use capital letters to refer to the columns. However, if you are using `Query` against the output of an array formula, such as the return from `ImportRange`, then you instead need to use `Col1`, `Col2`, ... to refer to the columns. So, your example query string would need to read:

```
"select Col2 where Col5 contains 'Warszawa'"
```

Working example:

```
=Query(ImportRange("0AtEH2Kw9zfIodEQ2dFNFam9sdEFEZlVnNEV3ZEZMZEE", "data!A:G"), "select Col3, count(Col4) group by Col3 order by count(Col4) desc label count(Col4) 'count'")
```

I've no idea why it doesn't just let you use names from a header row.

Comment: Thanks! Curious where you found this hint! FYI, this is also a problem when you do nestings of queries/sorts/transposes such as `=query(transpose(query(A1:B3;"select * where B>=2"));"select A")` (it says Column [A] doesn't exist). But it works if I use Col1.

Comment: I was having problems querying an imported range, so I googled for `google spreadsheet query importrange` and landed on an example which used the `Col1 ... Coln` convention.

Comment: @George. Is there any settings that I need to do on the source spreadsheet? I have successfully imported data but only numbers are imported, cells that should contain strings are blank.

Comment: For some reason, I get the error "NO_COLUMN: Col1" when I try to apply query referring to a single cell that contains a `=filter...` formula.

Comment: Yeah, and if you need to convert an array, referenced by A, B, C, to the one referenced by Col1, Col2, Col3. just enclose it in `{ }`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can try the `FILTER` function in this case and then you don't need to bother with SQL. :)

`=FILTER(ImportRange("0ArsOaWajjzv9dEdGTUZCWFc1NnFva05uWkxETVF6Q0E"; "Kuchnia polska!B3:B40"); ImportRange("0ArsOaWajjzv9dEdGTUZCWFc1NnFva05uWkxETVF6Q0E"; "Kuchnia polska!e3:e40")="Warszava")`

Although I admit that it's not so pretty because of the two `importRange` functions.

Hope it helped anyway.