# Google Sheets Error: column doesn't load when querying multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, average, spreadsheet

I'm trying to query two separate sheets to a cell in my budget. One of the sheets is a google form I use to track my daily cash transactions, and the other is a ledger I'm using to input my bank transactions.

If I query either one of the sheets like this, either works fine:

```
=SUM(QUERY('Form Responses'!$A$1:$C$400,"SELECT B,C WHERE B = 'Coffee'",1))/$D$1
```

```
=SUM(QUERY(Ledger!$A$1:$C$400,"SELECT B,C WHERE B = 'Coffee'",1))/$D$1
```

HOWEVER, when I try to combine them like this...

```
=SUM(QUERY({'Form Responses'!$A$1:$C$400;Ledger!$A$1:$C$400},"SELECT B,C WHERE B = 'Coffee'",1))/$D$1
```

I get this error:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: B
```

I have gone deep into forums and SO, and have found lots of tips - but none of them work and many of them are depreciated. Can anyone solve this issue at a glance?

I don't understand how there can be a 'Column B' when they're queried individually, but not when queried together.

Comment: When you use an array of data for `query()` - you should use `Col1`, `Col2`, etc., instead of `A`,`B`, etc. In your case `"SELECT Col2, Col3 WHERE Col2 = 'Coffee'"` should help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google spreadsheet Query Error - column doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650331/google-spreadsheet-query-error-column-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=SUM(QUERY({'Form Responses'!$A$1:$C$400; Ledger!$A$1:$C$400},
 "select Col2,Col3 where Col2 = 'Coffee'", 1))/$D$1
```